# can't change update server in lubuntu 17.10

Tags: lubuntu, 17.10, repository

I have Lubuntu 17.10 and when I try to change update server in preferences > software&updates it can find the best server but when I select it and it asks to reload before closing, it shows an error dialog box contains:

```
E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
```

I tried to uncheck

> http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu artful Release

but uncheck does not do anything!!!

I used `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` to see repositories but even when I removed all of them there are a lot of repo s in preferences > software&updates and **wine** repo is still checked !!!

Comment: Try to do this from terminal with `sudo add-apt-repository -r "http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu artful"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `sudo ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d` and then removed two items from list by running:

`sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-artful.list.save`

`sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-artful.list`

and now `sudo apt-get update` works great